# JQuery : Inserting "()" inside the :contains() Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I insert the text "()" inside the :contains() Selector, I am getting the following error

```
    Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "X(")
```

I will give my sample

```
   $("div#list li:contains("X(")").remove();
```

How to overcome this?

EDIT : I am using jquery-1.4.1.

Comment: But what string you are looking for: X( or X(" ?

Comment: `$('div#list li:contains("X(")').remove();` http://jsbin.com/araxed/2/edit

Comment: OP will you consider to answer question?

Answer (score 2):

Just use one string with `'`

```
$('div#list li:contains("X(")').remove();
```

**Edit**: in version 1.4.1 there was yet a bug with `:contains` selector's escaping. In this case you have to write your own `RegExp` to find the element:

```
var searchRegex = new RegExp("X\\(", "g"),
    result = $('div#list li').filter(function (i, el) {
        return $(el).text().match(searchRegex);
    });
result.remove();
```

Comment: Where the closing breaket of contains???

Comment: You kidding? `("X(")` **(**"X("**)**

Comment: @ManishJangir: it is already there

Comment: It's a shame this need for reputation lol

Comment: Who downvoted can please explain? I'm curious!

Comment: @LightStyle : your answer is not working.it s showing the same error

Comment: Which string are you searching?

Comment: @LightStyle :I am searching X( . I am not  down voted.

Comment: See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BaaNq/), it works

Comment: @LightSytle : I am working on jquery 1.4.1.js

Comment: I tried with jQuery 1.0 and it works, it is not a matter of version. Please post a fiddle with what have you tried so far

Comment: In fiddler, Lowest version showing is 1.6.4. How to check jquery 1.4.1 version.Please help me on this.. Mostly I think problem might be in jquery 1.4.1.

Answer (score 2):

It is an escaping issue but it would be much simpler to do this:

```
 $('div#list li:contains("X(")').remove();
```

or

```
 $("div#list li:contains('X(')").remove();
```

Comment: Check the other answers, this is a dupe...

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer

```
$("div#list li:contains('X(\")')").remove();
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/4F3JF/